# Cast int96 timestamp from parquet to golang

Tags: go, parquet

Having this 12 byte array (int96) to timestamp.

[128 76 69 116 64 7 0 0 48 131 37 0]

How do I cast it to timestamp?

I understand the first 8 byte should be cast to int64 millisecond that represent an epoch datetime.

Answer (score 13):

The first 8 bytes are time in nanosecs, not millisecs. They are not measured from the epoch either, but from midnight. The date part is stored separatly in the last 4 bytes as [Julian day number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

Here is the result of an experiment I did earlier that may help. I stored '2000-01-01 12:34:56' as an int96 and dumped with parquet-tools:

```
$ parquet-tools dump hdfs://path/to/parquet/file | tail -n 1
value 1: R:0 D:1 V:117253024523396126668760320
```

Since 117253024523396126668760320 = 0x60FD4B3229000059682500, the 12 bytes are 00 60 FD 4B 32 29 00 00 | 59 68 25 00, where | shows the boundary between the time and the date parts.

00 60 FD 4B 32 29 00 00 is the time part. We need to reverse the bytes because int96 timestamp use a reverse byte order, thus we get 0x000029324BFD6000 = 45296 * 10^9 nanoseconds = 45296 seconds = 12 hours + 34 minutes + 56 seconds.

59 68 25 00 is the date part, if we reverse the bytes we get 0x00256859 = 2451545 as the Julian day number, which [corresponds to](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/jdconverter?ID=AA&jd=2451545) 2000-01-01.

Answer (score 4):

@Zoltan you definitely deserve the vote although you didn't supply a Golang sulotion.

Thanks to you and to https://github.com/carlosjhr64/jd

I wrote a function `func int96ToJulian(parquetDate []byte) time.Time`

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WOJz-_GDf_c)

```
func int96ToJulian(parquetDate []byte) time.Time {
    nano := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(parquetDate[:8])
    dt := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(parquetDate[8:])

    l := dt + 68569
    n := 4 * l / 146097
    l = l - (146097*n+3)/4
    i := 4000 * (l + 1) / 1461001
    l = l - 1461*i/4 + 31
    j := 80 * l / 2447
    k := l - 2447*j/80
    l = j / 11
    j = j + 2 - 12*l
    i = 100*(n-49) + i + l

    tm := time.Date(int(i), time.Month(j), int(k), 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    return tm.Add(time.Duration(nano))
}
```

Comment: I do not know any Go (which is why I did not provide any code in my answer), but your use of binary.BigEndian above suggest that there is a binary.LittleEndian as well (which I confirmed with a quick Google search). If you used that, you wouldn't have to reverse the bytes manually, since that's exactly what endianness means.

Comment: This is working but what are those magic numbers? Wish those would have been well commented/documented