# Int96Value to Date string

Tags: scala, datetime, parquet

When reading a parquet file (using Scala) I read the timestamp field back as:

```
Int96Value{Binary{12 constant bytes, [0, 44, 84, 119, 54, 49, 0, 0, -62, -127, 37, 0]}}
```

How can I convert it to a date string?

Comment: Please be mindful with the tags you put on your question.  There is no point to you attracting [tag:java] experts to a question about [tag:scala].

Comment: What is the library you are using to read the parquet file?

Comment: @JoeC I tagged it as Java as I am fine with a Java solution as well.
Though your point is very valid and I should have clarified this in the question.

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy I am using parquet-avro version 1.9.0 to read the file.

Comment: Similar question for Go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103762/cast-int96-timestamp-from-parquet-to-golang/53104516

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.time supports Julian days.

Credits to ygor for doing the research and finding out how to interpret the 12 bytes of your array.

```
    byte[] int96Bytes = { 0, 44, 84, 119, 54, 49, 0, 0, -62, -127, 37, 0 };

    // Find Julian day
    int julianDay = 0;
    int index = int96Bytes.length;
    while (index > 8) {
        index--;
        julianDay <<= 8;
        julianDay += int96Bytes[index] & 0xFF;
    }

    // Find nanos since midday (since Julian days start at midday)
    long nanos = 0;
    // Continue from the index we got to
    while (index > 0) {
        index--;
        nanos <<= 8;
        nanos += int96Bytes[index] & 0xFF;
    }

    LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDate.MIN
            .with(JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY, julianDay)
            .atTime(LocalTime.NOON)
            .plusNanos(nanos);
    System.out.println("Timestamp: " + timestamp);
```

This prints:

> Timestamp: 2017-10-24T03:01:50

I’m not happy about converting your byte array to an `int` and a `long` by hand, but I don’t know Parquet will enough to use the conversions that are probably available there. Use them if you can.

It doesn’t matter which `LocalDate` we use as starting point since we are changing it to the right Julian day anyway, so I picked `LocalDate.MIN` just to pick one.

The way I read the documentation, Julian days are always in the local time zone, that is, no time zone is understood, and they always start at midday (not midnight).

**Link:** [Documentation of `JulianFields` in java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html)

Comment: This is what I ended up using. https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-hive/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/hive/parquet/ParquetTimestampUtils.java#L45-L62

Answer (score 3):

I did some research for you. The `Int96` format is quite specific a seems to be deprecated.

Here is a [discussion](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/pull/49) about converting `Int96` to `Date`.

Based on this, I created following piece of code:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import java.util.Date
    import org.apache.parquet.example.data.simple.{Int96Value, NanoTime}
    import org.apache.parquet.io.api.Binary

    val int96Value = new Int96Value(Binary.fromConstantByteArray(Array(0, 44, 84, 119, 54, 49, 0, 0, -62, -127, 37, 0)))
    val nanoTime = NanoTime.fromInt96(int96Value)
    val nanosecondsSinceUnixEpoch = (nanoTime.getJulianDay - 2440588) * (86400 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000) + nanoTime.getTimeOfDayNanos
    val date = new Date(nanosecondsSinceUnixEpoch / (1000 * 1000))
    println(date)
  }
```

However, it prints `Sun Sep 27 17:05:55 CEST 2093`. I am not sure, if this is a date, that you expected.

**Edit:** using `Instance` as suggested:

```
val nanosInSecond = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
val instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(nanosecondsSinceUnixEpoch / nanosInSecond, nanosecondsSinceUnixEpoch % nanosInSecond)
println(instant) // prints 2093-09-27T15:05:55.933865216Z
```

Comment: You should prefer to create a modern [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) over am outdated `Date`. The latter class has design problems and [the modern date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with. And has nanosecond precision, BTW.