# Converting ParquetSharp.Int96 to System.DateTime

Tags: c#

I am using ParquetSharp to read a parquet file.  One of the columns is typed as Int96.  In reality it is a DateTime.  I need to convert said ParquetSharp.Int96 to a System.DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

I did this using the oddly named int A, int B, int C properties of the Int96 type.   These Properties correspond to the 4 byte blocks that make up the int96.

using info found  in here:
[Cast int96 timestamp from parquet to golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103762/cast-int96-timestamp-from-parquet-to-golang/53104516)
[Int96Value to Date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690299/int96value-to-date-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(there is some mention of magic numbers in these links.)

I was able to come up with this:

```
DateTime ConvertToDateTime(Int96 typed)
{
    var date = DateTime.FromOADate(typed.C - 2415018.5);
    var a = BitConverter.GetBytes(typed.A);
    var b = BitConverter.GetBytes(typed.B);

    var nano = a.Concat(b).ToArray();

    var nanoLong = BitConverter.ToInt64(nano, 0);

    var result = date.AddTicks(nanoLong / 100);
    return result;
}
```